# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup : Microsoft.VC80.CRT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, crt

The following error has occurred:

> An error occurred during the installation of assembly
>   'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,version="8.0.50727.42",type="win32",processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"'.
>   Please refer to Help and Support for more information.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1&EvtType=0xDF039760%25401201%25401

I tried all possible solutions but non of them worked , Please let me know if you are familiar with this issue

Answer (score 1):

As per this link, [Click here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/72f27c30-5307-49e3-85dc-12a9c4704296/sql-server-2008-setup-failure-win-7-x64-msi-error-1935-an-error-occurred-during-the-installation?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Download this package - **Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x64)** to solve the Problem.

Click here for [download the same](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21254)

Comment: I already did the same thing.
Now I am getting new error while installing MVC_++2005

**Error 1935. An error occurred during the installing of assembly.
'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.42",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64"**

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error, in an AMD MV, I solved it by installing:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14431

and

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347

I hope it helps you.